# Блок наезжает на другой блок.

Tags: html, css

Почему один блок с постом наезжает на другой?
[image]

Вот код:
http://jsfiddle.net/78TRR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы задаёте фиксированную высоту для него, а внутрь помещаете значительно больше текста.

Answer (score 3):

высоты поубирайте http://jsfiddle.net/78TRR/4/